# Bi-Directional Self-Referential Active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, self-reference, bidirectional

first week playing with rails and I'm a bit stuck on this active record relationship

I have 3 tables right now, Events, Fights and Fighters. Every fight belongs to an event and fighters can have many fights. I want to be able to store information in the fights table such as the winner, how the fight was won, the referee etc.

I've been doing some research and I think I'll need a bi-directional self-referential has many through relationship for the fights. Does this require 2 entries in the through table? If so, how can I query the fights while viewing an event without 2 records for each fight showing?

What would be the best way to store the winner if I want to show the fighters record on the fighters page? Have a winner_id and a loser_id in the table? This gets confusing when there can be draws and no contests.

There can also be fights with no outcome because they haven't happened yet. I'm thinking of using a seperate table for those.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a few more tables:

**Participants**

could support more than two fighters in a match (not sure of your domain, but this could be useful for tag-team wrestling)

- fight_id - foreign key to fight (belongs_to)
- fighter_id - foreign key to fight (belongs_to)

**Decision**

The decision could have alot of information like type = "KO", "TKO", etc. Other info like Judges voting.  Draws and no-decision would not go here

- fight_id - foreign key to fight (belongs_to)
- type
- winner_id
- loser_id
- dt - datetime for when the decision was reached

And edit fights to contain a field on status:

**Fights**

- status - (decision, no-decision, draw, cancelled, postponed, etc)